# AG-GRID Using material components without SystemJS

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use material components in my AG-GRID project.

I try and import the relevant stuff as per the website example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-material-design/)

```
import {GridOptions, Module, AllCommunityModules} from "@ag-grid-community/all-modules";
```

However this throws the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/shot/shot-list/shot-list.component.ts(33,56): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ag-grid-community/all-modules'.
```

I have installed both ag grid community and angular as per instructions [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/)

```
npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular
```

I have checked with npm list and it gives the following versions installed:

```
+-- ag-grid@18.1.2
+-- ag-grid-angular@23.0.3
+-- ag-grid-community@23.0.2
```

My app.module.ts has the following import:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

I am not using SystemJS.

I have experimented around and when I try importing directly from 'ag-grid-community' like so

```
import { GridOptions, Module, AllCommunityModules } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

It throws the following error:

```
ERROR in shot-list.component.ts(32,31): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/............/ag-grid-community/main"' has no exported member 'AllCommunityModules'.
```

Do I need to import something more in my app.modules.ts?
Am I doing something really stupid here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do but just remove `Module` and `AllCommunityModules` from the import.

- `ag-grid-community` has no exported member `Module`.
- `ag-grid-community` has no exported member `AllCommunityModules`.

  ```
  import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community';
  ```